# Having a div appear when a link within another div is hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

Im sure this is a simple question to answer and I'm sorry to be another noob asking this type of question but I have spent about 45 minutes trying to use other forum posts to get this to work and I can't figure it out. What I am wanting is that when a visitor on my page hovers their mouse over one of the links in my banner a bio div for that place in the wrapper appears. Not really sure how else to word it but here is the code I currently have and I have tried different things but this is the latest bunch of code I have written so far...

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner_list">
        <div class="column" id="column_1">
            <p><a href="" id="bittaford_link">Bittaford</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="column_2">
            <p><a href="" id="gateway_link">Gateway (Cattledown)</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="column_3">
            <p><a href="" id="ridgeway_link">Ridgeway (Plympton)</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="church_bio" id="bittaford_bio">Bittaford</div>
    <div class="church_bio" id="gateway_bio">Gateway</div>
    <div class="church_bio" id="ridgeway_bio">Ridgeway</div>
</div>
```

and the css behind it...

```
    .banner_list {
        width: 660px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        padding: 40px 60px;
        background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.9);
    }

        .banner_list p,
        .banner_list a,
        .banner_list h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: 100;
        }

        .column {
            width: 200px;
            margin-top: 50px;
            float: left;
        }

            #column_1, #column_2 {
                margin-right: 30px;
            }


.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    top: 728px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
}

    .church_bio {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #bittaford_bio #bittaford_link:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #gateway_bio #bittaford_link:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #ridgeway_bio #bittaford_link:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

I think I have given more code than I need to but I wasn't sure if it would be more helpful if you had all the code so far. Also trying to avoid js as much as possible.

Thanks in advance, Matt.

Comment: plz create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i know you say "avoid" but do you want a pure css solution or would you consider using javascropt / jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript onmouse over and on mouse out event and you need hide all church_bio by using display:none in css.

Css

```
.banner_list {
        width: 660px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        padding: 40px 60px;
        background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.9);
    }

        .banner_list p,
        .banner_list a,
        .banner_list h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: 100;
        }

        .column {
            width: 200px;
            margin-top: 50px;
            float: left;
        }

            #column_1, #column_2 {
                margin-right: 30px;
            }


.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    top: 728px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
}

    .church_bio {
display:none;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #bittaford_bio #bittaford_link:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #gateway_bio #bittaford_link:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #ridgeway_bio #bittaford_link:hover {
        background-color: red;
    }
```

JS

```
<script>
function show(id,type)
{
if (type==1)
{
document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";
}
if (type==2)
{

document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
}
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="banner_list">
        <div class="column" id="column_1">
            <p><a href="" onmouseover="show('bittaford_bio',1);"  onmouseout="show('bittaford_bio',2);" id="bittaford_link">Bittaford</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="column_2">
            <p><a href="" "  onmouseover="show('gateway_bio',1);"  onmouseout="show('gateway_bio',2);" id="gateway_link" >Gateway (Cattledown)</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="column_3">
            <p><a href=""  onmouseover="show('ridgeway_bio',1);"  onmouseout="show('ridgeway_bio',2);" id="ridgeway_link">Ridgeway (Plympton)</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="church_bio" id="bittaford_bio">Bittaford</div>
    <div class="church_bio" id="gateway_bio">Gateway</div>
    <div class="church_bio" id="ridgeway_bio">Ridgeway</div>
</div>
```

Comment: question is not tagged as `JS` or `jQuery`..plus CSS offers only 2 line solution for this!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Without a jsfiddle...it's pretty difficult to answer as m not a big fan of theory...and  you have put up your entire css/html, post only the relevant part next time!! ;)

dint read you complete code but here is simple way to get you started :
 [**startup jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fB5C/2/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="first"> i am a link</a>
<div class="show_on_hover"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .show_on_hover {
        border:1px solid #000;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display:none; /* hide by default */
    }
    a.first:hover + div.show_on_hover {
        display:block;  
       /*this is the trick....use "+" sign 
       to bind the "on-hover" element and to-show element/div */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't come around using javascript for this problem.

In case you are using jQuery, here is another solution:

```
$("#bittaford_link").mouseover(function() {
    $("#bittaford_bio").show();
});
$("#bittaford_link").mouseout(function() {
    $("#bittaford_bio").hide();
});
```

As for a css only solution: With this placement of the elements it won't work. What you could do is use the + operator, specify a container of content right after the link, align it with absolute coordinates where you want it to actually show and make it visible when hovering over the link.

**HTML**

```
<a href="" id="bittaford_link"></a><div id="bittaford_bio"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bittaford_link:hover + #bittaford_bio { display: block; }
#bittaford_bio { position: absolute; display: none; top: /* ... */, left: /* ... */ }
```

But this is ugly as hell, just use javascript ...